# Que técnica esse site usa para consumir todo o poder de processamento da maquina?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Esse site: https://ffbeequip.com/builder.html possui um sistema de criar uma build de equipamentos automática, ela vai testando todos os equipamentos possíveis até chegar na conclusão de qual ficou melhor no personagem. Existe uma opção de usar mais de 1 core do processador, e quando ativada usando todos os cores, o processamento vai a 100% instantaneamente, existe alguma função nativa no Chrome que permita manipular o uso do processador, para por exemplo usar toda sua capacidade?

Comment: Não, você não tem controle e nem poderia ter sob tal gerenciamento, se via APIs do navegador/motor pudesse algo assim ser gerenciado, com certeza seria usado para o "mal". Quem gerencia os processos e memória é o proprio motor do navegador de forma independente, fornecendo no máximo um simples painel para o usuário matar os processos do navegador (atalho Shift+Esc no Windows).

Answer (score 1):

O JavaScript, por padrão, é single thread: ele pode executar apenas um programa em uma CPU (core).

Acredito que para isso seria necessário utilizar Web Workers: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API.

> Web Workers são mecanismos que permitem que uma operação de um dado
>   script seja executado em uma thread diferente da thread principal da
>   aplicação Web. Permitindo que cálculos laboriosos sejam processados
>   sem que ocorra bloqueio da thread principal (geralmente associado à
>   interface).

Sendo assim seria possível utilizar workers em núcleos separados, permitindo até 100% de utilização da capacidade da CPU.

https://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/workers/basics/